# Android:What's the diff between "/sdcard" to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: android, sd-card

I used to use the `path="/sdcard/myapp"` to save data.
However,the compiler suggests me to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of hardcode `"/sdcard"`

My Question is:
**If I do this, would the users of myapp  lost their data when they updates？
AND, if true , how to prevent？**

Comment: I think it's just some sort of encapsulation, since physical path could change for many reasons, but method name will stay the same. I prefer Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() as well

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, certain device manufacturers might use a different path for the external storage. Some devices might not have external storage at all and consider a part of their onboard storage as external storage. At other times, "/sdcard" might be mapped to another storage area as well.

So it is generally not considered wise to use `"/sdcard".`

On the other hand, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is a system API and will always be supported by all device manufacturers. It will always correctly map to the storage area which is meant to be used as external storage for that particular device. So you can use this safely whenever you need a reference to the external storage directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not all devices have sdcard. Some have build in storage like tablets. Therefore you should using the external storage directory.

Could be that it is directory mapped to /sdcard but could be some other directory/mount.

To answer your question: no, they will not loose there data.